# Cursors in oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, cursor

I am trying to do a trigger that updates a status of a grade on update of the grade or a insert of a new one.
Thats my table

```
create table Enrollment (
   Student_ID char(9) not null,
   Course_ID char(5) not null,
   Registered_Date date,
   Grade NUMBER,
   Status varchar(4), 
   constraint pkEnrollment primary key (Student_ID, Course_ID));
```

That's my code so far and i don't know what's the problem

```
create or replace TRIGGER PASS_FAIL 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF GRADE ON ENROLLMENT
DECLARE
CURSOR change_grade IS 
select GRADE, STATUS from ENROLLMENT FOR UPDATE;
 newgrade ENROLLMENT.GRADE%type;
 newstatus ENROLLMENT.STATUS%type;
BEGIN
  OPEN change_grade;
  LOOP
  FETCH change_grade into newgrade,newstatus;
  IF newgrade>=60 THEN UPDATE ENROLLMENT SET STATUS = 'Pass' WHERE CURRENT OF change_grade;
  ELSE UPDATE ENROLLMENT SET STATUS = 'Fail' WHERE CURRENT OF change_grade;
  END IF;
  EXIT WHEN change_grade%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE change_grade;
END;
```

When i tried to change the grade i get

```
UPDATE "FELIX"."ENROLLMENT" SET GRADE = '10' WHERE ROWID = 'AAAGETAABAAALKJAAE' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '3332070'
ORA-04098: trigger 'FELIX.ELIGIBLE_ENROLLMENT' is invalid and failed re-validation


One error saving changes to table "FELIX"."ENROLLMENT":
Row 5: ORA-04098: trigger 'FELIX.ELIGIBLE_ENROLLMENT' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: what is the problem or error message?

Comment: When i tried to change the grade i get UPDATE "FELIX"."ENROLLMENT" SET GRADE = '10' WHERE ROWID = 'AAAGETAABAAALKJAAE' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '3332070'
ORA-04098: trigger 'FELIX.ELIGIBLE_ENROLLMENT' is invalid and failed re-validation


One error saving changes to table "FELIX"."ENROLLMENT":
Row 5: ORA-04098: trigger 'FELIX.ELIGIBLE_ENROLLMENT' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: as a starting point, does your trigger compile?  if not, what is the error message?

Comment: yes he is compiled successfully

Comment: Your ID columns are CHAR? Really?

Comment: @FelixKulish please update your answer with the trigger code you are using now as you appear to have changed it, judging by the error codes

Comment: i am getting the same error (ORA-04098) from the trigger above and from your suggestion. thanks for trying to help me...

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems excessively complicated unless the point is to learn about cursors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PASS_FAIL
   Before INSERT OR UPDATE 
   ON enrollment
   REFERENCING NEW AS New OLD AS Old
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
/******************************************************************************
   NAME:       PASS_FAIL
   PURPOSE:
   USED BY:
   REVISIONS:
   Ver        Date        Author           Description
   ---------  ----------  ---------------  ------------------------------------
   1.0              1. Created this trigger.

   NOTES:  

******************************************************************************/

BEGIN
   if :new.grade > 60 THEN
     :new.status := 'PASS';
   ELSE
     :new.status := 'FAIL';
   END IF; 
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      -- Log the error and then re-raise
      RAISE;
END PASS_FAIL;
```

Comment: the trigger above doesn't compile. i get Error: ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type

Comment: In any case, selecting from the table as part of a trigger is likely to be problematic.

Comment: so how can i change the status in another way?

Comment: @Felix  Kulish. Sorry this should be a before trigger. Code. Amended

Comment: the trigger is compiled successfully but when i change the grade i got the same error like from my trigger UPDATE "FELIX"."ENROLLMENT" SET GRADE = '10' WHERE ROWID = 'AAAGETAABAAALKJAAG' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '3332070'
ORA-04098: trigger 'FELIX.ELIGIBLE_ENROLLMENT' is invalid and failed re-validation


One error saving changes to table "FELIX"."ENROLLMENT":
Row 7: ORA-04098: trigger 'FELIX.ELIGIBLE_ENROLLMENT' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: please update your question with the trigger code you are using now.

Comment: @FelixKulish please post the code that worked for you so  others can see

Comment: it's stupid but i didn't know that you have to enable trigger in the sql developer after compile (he was not grey like when you disable it).When i did your trigger work like a charm. thanks again.

Comment: i have another question. If a want to change value in another table (with the student id from the trigger) in the trigger how could i get the student id that the change take place? :new.student_id doesn't work.

Comment: @FelixKulish  Why not ask a new question?